# How to post image to URL properly?

Tags: c#, http, stocktwits

I'm trying to post an image to the StockTwits API and am receiving a 422 error as a response saying that the image format can't be recognized. The image is a png file, so it should be a valid file format. I've tried using a jpeg with the same response.

Am I encoding the image incorrectly, or missing some configuration in the `HttpClient`?

```
public void Share(string text, string imageFilePath)
{
    using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            string      url             = stocktwitsCreateMessageUrl + "&" +
                                            "body="         + Core.Globals.UrlEncode(twit)  + "&" +
                                            "sentiment="    + StockTwitsSentiment.ToString().ToLower();

            byte[]      imageBytes      = File.ReadAllBytes(imageFilePath);
            HttpContent imageContent    = new ByteArrayContent(imageBytes);
            string      fileName        = Path.GetFileName(imageFilePath);
            formData.Add(imageContent, "chart", fileName); 
            HttpResponseMessage stockTwitsResponse  = await client.PostAsync(url, formData);
            Stream              responseContent     = await stockTwitsResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            string              result              = new StreamReader(responseContent).ReadToEnd();
            Print(result); // helper method
            if (!stockTwitsResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                LogErrorResponse(result, stockTwitsResponse);
                return;
            }
            else
                LogAndPrint(typeof(Custom.Resource), "ShareStockTwitsSentSuccessfully", new[] { Name }, Cbi.LogLevel.Information);
        }
}
```

Response:

> {
>
> "response": { "status": 422 },
>
> "errors": [ { "message": "We couldn't recognize the image format. Format must be one of: image/jpg image/jpeg image/pjpeg image/png image/x-png image/gif" } ]
>
> }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to set your `Content-Type` header to `"image/png"`!

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Adding the content-type to the imageContent object's headers solved the issue. Thanks!